# JsRender - How to render template from within template?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates, jsrender

How can I render a template from within a template in JSRender? In the previous jquery template, I could use

`{{tmpl(Languages) "#languageTemplate"}}`

In JSRender, I could find template composition examples in conditional statements and loops. I want to call the template independently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In JsRender

> {{for Languages tmpl="#languageTemplate"/}}

is more or less exactly equivalent to the following in jQuery Templates

> {{tmpl(Languages) "#languageTemplate"}}

In each case if Languages is an array, the languageTemplate will render once for each item, but if Languages is not an array, the template will render once.

Comment: Hi Boris. It is not working (I am using the latest code 'pre beta commit counter 9' from github). How can I pass the current variable scope to the sub template?

Comment: The following code worked `{{for #data tmpl="#languageTemplate"/}}`. Is this the correct usage? Also, is the current version beta? I read your comment from March that JSRender is in beta. But the project page says it is still pre beta.

Comment: Yes, that is correct for current syntax. (Now updated above).
The current JsRender API is very close to beta - but it is not yet officially beta, and won't be until JsViews has also reached the stable beta API design.

Comment: @BorisMoore Do you think you could help with this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100184/jsrender-how-to-call-an-external-template-from-a-nested-template

Answer (score 2):

One update to Boris's answer.  In Boris's latest documentation, you need to add "tmpl=" in front of the template name in the for loop to reference a template within a template.  So the final version would be:

{{for Languages tmpl="#languageTemplate"/}}

See his [demo](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/demos.html) to find more info

Comment: Yes, thanks, that is correct. Edited/corrected in my reply above.